# Generate 100% unique API keys in PHP

Tags: api, key, unique

What is the 'guaranteed' way to generate a unique API key?

I looked in many stackoverflow questions and all of them had a small chance of collision. I want it 100% chance of no collision (given no bit flips of course), not 99.999999999% or anything that is below 100%.

Regardless if it is 1 in 100^50, I want it to be 100% unique.

Are the API keys Google give unique?

Comment: Use an auto incremental number?

Comment: In that case, store all the keys you give out in a database, and check if they already exist.

Comment: Otherwise generate them while looking up whether it exists yet. It's not rocket science.

Comment: @PeeHaa True, but then probability of it taking more than a million years to compute is more than 0.

Is such a method almost impossible?

If it is then, then I guess I'll go with your solution anyway, I guess it works ;). I was just wondering if there could be a better neat one.

Comment: " True, but then probability of it taking more than a million years to compute is more than 0" It works for youtube why wouldn't it work for you?